# Java selenium scrool code not working in new tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing java selenium. Everything is ok, but when the new tab is opened, the scrool code I added does not open in the new tab? How can I include the codes I wrote in the new tab?

I want the page to go down in the new tab and click on the image I want

Comment: Before stating the problem, first you should at least drop the snippets of your code so that other's can helps you on the problem

Answer (score 1):

*****This is the code scheme I wrote*****

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\*\\Desktop\\driver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.hepsiburada.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Kabul Et']")).click();
        ////input[@name='query_text']
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='desktopOldAutosuggestTheme-UyU36RyhCTcuRs_sXL9b']")).sendKeys("HBCV00000ODHHV"); ////bu arama çubuğuna yazıyor
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='desktopOldAutosuggestTheme-UyU36RyhCTcuRs_sXL9b']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);  ////bu tıklattırıyor
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 300);");
        Thread.sleep(5000);         
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@type='comfort']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jsx.executeScript("scroll(0, 300);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling to web element:

```
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://mrslavchev.com");
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        //This will scroll the page till the element is found
        WebElement footer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='site-info-text']"));
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the codes didn't work. The code you have already written below gave an error.
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);*****

Comment: You need to replace element with concrete element you want to scroll to: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@type='comfort']")) or WebElement 
 element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@type='comfort']")) and pass the element

Comment: Check the updated example